# UrlDecode and ASCII characters in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, escaping, url-encoding

I'm working on a project that is integrated with a payment provider (epdq). They pass variables of the successful payment back in a querystring to our website. Part of the querystring that is passed back includes the customers name. We have noticed that if someone enters a special character, such as '£' the querystring parameters is returned like so: CN=Mr+%A3Test+Test

This is quite strange because I thought the UrlEncoded value for the £ symbol was %C2%A3.

Regardless, this is causing issues because we have to decode the values passed back in the querystring and get their true value, in this instance the £ symbol.

I've tried two different ways of doing it:

```
            foreach (var key in querystring.Keys)
        {
            var enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            Logger.Debug(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring.ToString(), enc)[key.ToString()]);
            Logger.Debug(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(querystring.Get(key.ToString()), enc));
        }
```

I've tried it with both iso-8859-1 and utf-8. Both however convert the string to 'Mr �Test Test', obviously a character it hasn't been able to convert back properly.

Other than using a regular expression and searching the string for a whole host of possible characters that the customer could input, and then convert them from their ASCII equivalent (I note in ASCII %A3 is the £ symbol) I'm not sure where else to go with this.

Can anyone provide any pointers?

Thanks for your time in advance

dotdev

Comment: So you don’t know what encoding the payment provider uses to encode there querystring data? You need to know this, just assuming the encoding is why you have an encoding mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this encoding:  Encoding.GetEncoding("1252");

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately that seems to make no odds whatsoever - it's still not converted to a character it recognises...

Comment: What is the result you got when you tried this encoding?

Comment: The same as i did before - the unrecognisable character ui.e. the ? in the triangle....

Answer (score -1):

I know I am late to answer but you can try the following code:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(key.Replace("%A3", "£"));
```

Comment: This is what happens when an encoding mismatch occurs and the suggested solution is merely a bandaid and doesn’t fix the root of the problem. Sorry, but there is no escaping the fact, this is bad advice.